# How can I debug my MVC3 site with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC3 website. I have some javascript in my .cshtml file:

```
<div>hello!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () { alert("ready!"); })
</script>
```

Google Chrome's built-in debugger doesn't see this javascript snippet, so I can't debug it.

How can I set a breakpoint in this javascript snippet in Google Chrome's built-in debugger?

Comment: break the function onto multiple lines. Then, you can set a breakpoint on the `alert` line.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if this is located within an `@Html.BeginForm` code block in Razor view engine, you may have to change how you're creating that block (curly braces may break compilation of your view).

Comment: @Jim: No, you won't.  Razor only looks for the closing `}` outside any HTML tags (in code context).

Comment: @SLaks: That's not true.  I've specifically run into this issue with Razor's inability to parse multiple nested blocks inside of a `@using(Html.BeginForm())` block.  This was just after the official release of MVC3, it may have changed.

Comment: @Jim: I'm pretty sure you're wrong.  Can you show me an example of troublesome markup?

Comment: @Slaks: Sorry, man. It's code for one of the largest companies in the world.  I'm not going to mess with that.  But, I can assure you, changing it from the disposable to two separate calls as in the answer I posted fixed the problem on multiple views.  Someone on my team submitted the issue to Microsoft and never heard back.

Comment: Nope, has nothing to do with multiple lines. (That was just a sample. My real code, with multiple lines, can't be debugged in Chrome because it's a javascript snippet, part of my .cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, works great for me:

1. Go to the `Scripts` tab
2. You will see a dropdown list of all referenced javascript files, select the one that corresponds to the inline scripts (`:9038` in my screenshot below)
3. Set your breakpoint

[image]

You might also consider [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) as an alternative.

Comment: My script doesn't show up there. Or at least, not consistently. Neither does it show up in Chrome's FireBug Lite extension.

Comment: Marking this as the answer; it sometimes works: on occasion, my script is listed in the drop down. Other times, it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC3, running the razor view engine, I've had braces really mess up the parsing of the view.

For instance, if you have:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
<div>hello!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () { alert("ready!"); });
</script>
}
```

You may have issues with the script's braces.  Try changing it to:

```
  @{ Html.BeginForm(); }
    <div>hello!</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () { 
            alert("ready!"); 
       });
    </script>
   @{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

This may or may not be the answer to your question, but it took me *forever* to figure out what was wrong with a few of my forms.  I wasn't embedding scripts in them, though.. it was blocks for conditional logic that would break everything for me.

**EDIT**
After a little more research, I found an issue someone had which led me to the solution: aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7551.

My commit message (from a codebase I don't physically have access to any longer) suggests it may have been bad markup. The dev who wrote the offending pages liked to use capitalized tags, even though we were using XHTML 1.1 doctype. He also had a lot of attributes being conditionally compiled and/or populated.  For example:

```
<div class="something @myHelper(someFlag)"></div>
<div @{ isSomeFlag ? <text>class="asdf"</text> : "" }></div>
```

My solution should be considered a temporary fix.

Comment: Your first example causes no trouble for me with Razor, and I personally have never experienced any issues with the Razor parser with respect to JS vs. C# braces.

Comment: @Kirk: I've used the first example a number of times myself.  This may be an edge case, but I did encounter it three or so times.  All of which were someone else's code, of course. :P

Comment: @Kirk: Also, you're probably like me and avoid using too much logic in a view.  That was very common on these pages, ~75-100 lines of control structures.

Comment: Code and markup are mutually exclusive; there is no situation in which Razor can expect both markup and `}`.

Comment: @SLaks: I would tweak the code and post an example if I had access to the codebase still, but I recently moved and left that position.  I'll reach out to someone who is still on the team and see if I can get a real example.

Comment: Nope, sorry, the problem isn't curly braces. It's that script inside .cshtml doesn't even show up in Chrome's debugger.

Comment: @Judah: Did you try wrapping the script tags in `<text></text>` tags?

Comment: @SLaks: I wasn't able to get the code from my old coworker.  I found an issue someone had which led me to the solution: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7551, and my commit message suggests it may have been bad markup.  The dev who wrote the offending pages liked to use capitalized tags, even though we were using XHTML 1.1 doctype.  That *would* explain it, I guess.

Comment: @SLaks: Do you have any idea why using the disposable form of the `Html.BeginForm` would be less forgiving of poorly-written HTML markup?

Comment: @SLaks: I also updated my answer with some examples of the wackiness I encountered regularly (and on the offending pages).

Comment: @Jim: Tags, including `<text>`, are statements, not expressions.  You can't put them in conditionals.

Comment: @Slaks: the `<text>` tags may or may not have been there.  It's been a couple months since I last saw that code.  But, there was a lot of weirdness like that, and it made me want to bang my head on my desk every time I saw it.  Thanks for asking more about, sorry I couldn't provide the actual code.