# How to debug a modal dialogue's document.ready Javascript which is defined in a razor view?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, razor

My web application is one of those "single page" styled applications which replaces `<div>` content via ajax. In the case where we wish to show a modal dialogue to the user, this function is called:

```
function OpenWindow(name, title, params) 
{
    var winParams = SetWindowParameters(name, title, params);
    var container = $('div.k-content[id=\'' + name + '\']');

    if (container.length > 0) 
        container.data("kendoWindow").destroy();

    container = $('<div/>', { id: name }).css('display', 'none');

    container.appendTo($('body'))

    if (params.content) 
        container.html(params.content);

    var window = container.kendoWindow(winParams);

    window.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
}
```

One sample value for `params` is such:

```
params = { content: response, draggable: true, wizard: true };
```

And `response` contains the result from `public ActionResult ShowSomePopup` which returns a `ViewResult` object.

So another function makes an ajax request, gets some HTML back from the server and then passes that response object to `OpenWindow`.

This view I'm returning is a Razor View. The cshtml file looks sort of like this:

```
<div id="SomeDiv">
    <!-- the rest of the form -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        //some code
    });
</script>
```

I've found:

- [How can I debug my MVC3 site with Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617657/how-can-i-debug-my-mvc3-site-with-chrome) - Accepted answer is 6 years old and my Chrome looks very different. If I load up the dev tools and click on the script associated with my page, the content of this file is empty regardless if I use Firebug or Chrome's debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbjVU.png and the second answer is not helpful for me as my `<script type="text/javascript> ... </script>` is **not** 'within' any of the braces for the razor code.
- [Using Chrome JavaScript Debugger / How to break on page loading events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727370/using-chrome-javascript-debugger-how-to-break-on-page-loading-events) - I don't understand the accepted answer, but the second answer with a +100 Bounty does not work for me. I checked the `DOMContentLoaded` checkbox it never triggers for me.
- [How can I debug javascript contained in $(document).ready()?](http://javascript.qahowto.com/How-can-I-debug-javascript-contained-in-documentready-javascript-jquery-debugging-google-chrome-breakpoints-ed5a77) - Again, since the script is defined in a cshtml file it does not show up under the `Sources` tab in the debugger.

The **only** solution I've found is to simply move the contents of the cshtml's script into a JS file and call *that* function from the cshtml's `$(document).ready` script. But this is a colossal pain in the butt when I have *hundreds* of view files; I can't really take the time to go through and move everything all around.

**The question:** How can I use Chrome to debug a modal dialogue's document.ready function which is defined in a razor view?

Answer (score 0):

Write "debugger" in your js in a cshtml file so that Chrome hits the breakpoint and then you can step through when your browser developer tools is open.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      debugger;
      alert("Hello world");
    })
  
  </script>
</div>
```

Other references: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: Not a viable solution?